# Jupyter Notebook with python 3 not running

Tags: python-3.x, kernel, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I cannot open jupyter notebook with Python 3. I have Anaconda for Python 2 and Anaconda for Python 3 installed (both 64 bit for Windows). If I run jupyter notebook for Python 2 everything works fine but with Python 3 it does not work. I already reinstalled Anaconda 3 (4.2 Version = Python 3.5) but that did not help. I also tried out all the google results. I still get the following error when i run jupyter notebook from the anacoda prompt. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
(C:\Users\Myamoto\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Myamoto>jupyter notebook
_cffi_ext.c
AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(209): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/un.h': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import notebook.notebookapp
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 31, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 26, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\Myamoto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'
```

Answer (score 10):

```
    pip uninstall pyzmq
```

after did that

```
    pip install pyzmq.
```

Thanks to Muten_Roshi. 
this method works nice.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is with pyzmq, but running:

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
```

may end up with error `Cannot uninstall 'pyzmq'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

If you're using Anaconda, such chain of commands may help (it actually fixed my problem):

```
conda uninstall pyzmq 
conda install pyzmq 
conda install jupyter
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the similar problem with spyder.
I uninstalled all the packages that were creating issues and I uninstalled spyder as well.

```
Conda remove packages
conda install packages
```

it started working again.

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution which worked for me.
reinstall pyzmq in python3

If any of you guys got the same issue I hope that helps to solve it.